# Testing framework for windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

anyone know any framework that we can use to test windows phone 7 apps. In android  I can see there is a test framework called robotium. Is there any same kind of framework in windows phone world?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Silverlight Unit Test Framework, which is installed when you install the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com). You might find this post by Roger Peters handy in getting started: http://www.smartypantscoding.com/a-cheat-sheet-for-unit-testing-silverlight-apps-on-windows-phone-7